# Lifting form submitted data in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a form component where I currently submit a form to a URL and return data from the successful request, but because this component is modularized the data returned is not accessible by my other components in my application and I was wondering if I could keep the form submission request logic in this component (Header), but lift up the response data to a function that is set at parent level which can be stored in a state and shared with other components in my application.

At the moment my solution is working as intended as the data parameter is coming back `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` of form submission and pointing to the `this.props.onFormSubmit(res.data)`

index.js (Parent):

```
import React from "react"
import Header from '../components/content/header';

class IndexPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  
      this.state = {
          sleep_data: [],
      }
    }

    onFormSubmit(e, data){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e)
        console.log(data) // undefined
    }

    render() {
        const sleep = this.state.sleep_data || [];
        const {code, state} = queryString.parse(location.search)

        return (
            <Layout>
              <SEO title="Home" />
              <Header url={location.href} code={code} state={state} sleep_data={this.state.sleep_data} onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}/>
            </Layout>
          )
        }
    }
      
export default IndexPage;
```

Header (Form):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import axios from 'axios';
var dt = DateTime.local();
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.setStartDate = this.setStartDate.bind(this);
        this.setEndDate = this.setEndDate.bind(this);
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            startDate: '',
            endDate: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            startDate: new DateTime.local().minus({ days: 7 }).ts,
            endDate: dt.toMillis(new Date())
        });
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("onFormSubmit()")
        console.log(this.state.startDate)
        console.log(this.state.endDate)
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/tokens', {
            params: {
                code: this.props.code,
                state: this.props.state,
                start_date: DateTime.fromMillis(this.state.startDate).toISODate(),
                end_date: DateTime.fromMillis(this.state.endDate).toISODate()
            }
        }).then(function(res){
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
            this.props.onFormSubmit(res.data)
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err) // TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
        })
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div className="flex-row">
                <h3 className="text-low-purple-300"><u>Generate your report in three clicks</u></h3>
                <ol>
                    <li className="text-lg font-bold mb-5 mt-5 text-low-purple-200">Step 1: Pick a date range</li>
                    <form onSubmit={ this.onFormSubmit }>
                        <div className="w-full px-3 mb-5">
                            <label className="mr-4">Start Date:</label>
                            <DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.setStartDate} className="text-black text-center rounded-md p-2" name="startDate" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-full px-3">
                            <label className="mr-5">End Date:</label>
                            <DatePicker selected={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.setEndDate} className="text-black text-center rounded-md p-2" name="endDate" />
                        </div>
                        <li className="text-lg font-bold mt-5 text-low-purple-200">Step 2: Click submit</li>
                        
                        <button className="text-xl font-bold bg-mid-purple-500 hover:bg-mid-purple-700 w-64 py-5 px-5 rounded-md">Run Free Analysis</button>
                    </form>
                </ol>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Where are you calling `onFormSubmit` that is defined in `Header` component? `form` in `Header` component, on submission calls `this.props.onFormSubmit`. You probably want to call `this.onFormSubmit` on `form` submission and once the data has been fetched, you then call `this.props.onFormSubmit` with the required data as argument.

Comment: @Yousaf thank you for the quick response. Thanks for pointing that out. The code I shared was outdated. I just edited the code in my question and provided the proper error. As you can see, when I set `this.props.onFormSubmit(res.data)` the error is being called

Comment: Try passing arrow function instead of a regular function to the `catch` block.

Comment: In my previous comment, i meant to say `then()` block instead of `catch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an arrow function inside the .then() and .catch() methods in order to use the `this` of the component. In `function () {}`  the `this` has the scope of the function ().

```
onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("onFormSubmit()")
        console.log(this.state.startDate)
        console.log(this.state.endDate)
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/tokens', {
            params: {
                code: this.props.code,
                state: this.props.state,
                start_date: DateTime.fromMillis(this.state.startDate).toISODate(),
                end_date: DateTime.fromMillis(this.state.endDate).toISODate()
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
            this.props.onFormSubmit(res.data)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err) // TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
            // you may use `this` here as well, if needed
        })
    }
```

Read more [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/)

Comment: That was it. Thank you!